# Authenticated API call to AWS with requests

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests

I am running a django application with some data in an AWS bucket. Data is mostly files (powerpoint, word etc..). When I create a new file I get a link attached to it which I show in my REST list view like:

`"store_file": "https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/myfile?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXXXExpires=1571731023"`

I would like to get this file by doing an authenticated request to the endpoint with the library `requests` and I don't get it to work. 
I get a 200 when doing this:

```
def get_data(method='get'):
    endpoint = "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/pathtomyfile?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Signature=XXXExpires=1571731023"
    r = requests.request(method, endpoint)
    return r.status_code

get_data()
```

But it doesn't download my file

What works is doing it with the AWS CLI like `aws s3 cp s3://pathtomyfileinbucket /pathtomysavelocation/filename.pptx`

Even though this works it's not good for my use case, since I want to use it on different machines and with tests etc...

I was also trying to use `aws_requests_auth` like:

```
auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key='...',
                        aws_secret_access_key='...',
                        aws_host='restapiid.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
                        aws_region='eu-west-1',
                        aws_service='execute-api')

response = requests.get('https://restapiid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pathtomyfile',
                         auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Is there a way to do what I want to do?? I am grateful for any help. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. You're not asking it to download the file. What *exactly* do you want to do with that request?

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Yes you are absolutely right.... I added a ```with open('/pathtowhereIwantthefile', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)``` and it is donwloading my file..... Is this an OK way to do it though?? I am wondering because my AWS credentials are in the link...

Comment: `AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXXX` aren't your secrets. They refer to the Id of your keys and a signature crafted specifically for that file. And you're sending this over https anyway, so the URL parameters are encrypted.

Comment: Ahhh yes ok... Thanks @dirkgroten..... And will I be able to do this call for - let's say - forever? Or will the ``Èxpires``` argument take away my access with this signature?

Comment: The expiry you're showing here is October 22, 2019, 07:57 UTC. So it looks like they are just valid for a short time. But I don't really understand what you're doing here. Pre-signed URLs are for **uploading** objects, that's why they are valid only a limited time (and can be used only once). Not for **downloading** objects. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: thanks again. Well what I am doing: I configured my app so that I can upload my media files in a private media folder since I cannot allow public access. Now I want to download the files with the user that has correct credentials. Is that not a way it could work?

Comment: So I guess the Expiration date is from the presigned URL that was created when I uploaded the file maybe?

Comment: To be more precise: Every time I upload a file, a link like this appears on my Object that I created. So I query the object, get the URL as endpoint and to call it and download the file.

Comment: No... now I have a 403... damn

Comment: I solved it by creating new pre signed urls for each download.... I think this is also the idea of psu as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-generate_presigned_url.py.html. Quote: ```Sharing an S3 object is the intended use of S3 presigned URLs.```